# Map wont give values in Dictionary

Tags: dictionary

I have a dataframe i created called df
[Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZxp5.png)
. Then I applied i dictionary called my_dic [my_dic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWH3A.png) using. `df['SKU']= df['PRODUCTO'].map(my_dic)`. But, I get only nan in the new 'SKU' columns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my question, seems the dictionary didn´t work correctly, because i read it as an excel file